# Terminal WSL2 para phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Estoy empezando a desarrollar en WSL2 y uso el IDE Phpstorm
asi como hay un plugin en vscode para conectarse a la consola de wsl2
no encontre para phpstorm, solo lei que hay alternativas alguien sabe como configurarlo?

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

La versión de PHPStorm 2019.3 ya permite ejecutar los interpretadores desde WSL https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2019/10/phpstorm-2019-3-eap-7/

De todas maneras, si realmente querés una integración plena con el sistema de archivos de WSL2 lo mejor es ejecutar PHPStorm directamente desde tu instalación WSL a través de X Server https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/